# HALL SPI Transmit (STMF407)

Tags: c++

Hola alguien me puede ayudar con esta funcion :

```
HAL_SPI_Transmit(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
```

en especial size y timeout , no entiendo bien a que se refiere cada parámetro

Comment: No soy experto pero deduzco que Size es el tamaño de la data que quieres transmitir, y Timeout es el tiempo máximo de transmisión. Pero pienso que la información más precisa debe estar en la documentación.

Answer (score 0):

Todo está explicado de manera clara y concisa en [la documentación](http://www.disca.upv.es/aperles/arm_cortex_m3/llibre/st/STM32F439xx_User_Manual/group__spi__exported__functions__group2.html#ga02ec86e05d0702387c221f90b6f041a2), tal vez no lo entiendas por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> ```
> HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_SPI_Transmit ( SPI_HandleTypeDef * hspi, 
>                                      uint8_t *           pData, 
>                                      uint16_t            Size, 
>                                      uint32_t            Timeout 
>                                    )
> ```
>
> Transmite cierta cantidad de datos en modo bloqueante.
>
> **Parámetros**
>
> - **`hspi`** puntero a la estructura `SPI_HandleTypeDef` que contiene la información de configuración para el módulo SPI.
> - **`pData`** puntero al búfer de datos.
> - **`Size`** cantidad de datos a ser enviados.
> - **`Timeout`** duración del tiempo de espera.

Como puedes ver, `Size` es la cantidad de datos a ser enviados mientras que `Timeout` es el [tiempo que esperará el sistema antes de considerar que la tarea de la función ha fallado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeout_%28computing%29).